# Custom WooCommerce Shipping Method

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have this working code which generating and saving properly a custom shipping method under woocommerce setting > shipping zones.

My problem is that I can't make the shipping method show on the checkout page.

Any help on how to resolve this issue and maybe extend the code a bit would be greatly appreciated.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_shipping_methods', 'add_local_shipping');
function add_local_shipping($methods) {
    $methods['local_shipping'] = 'Local_Shipping_Method';
    return $methods;
}

class Local_Shipping_Method extends WC_Shipping_Method {

            public function __construct($instance_id = 0) {
                $this->id = 'local_shipping';
                $this->instance_id = absint($instance_id);
                $this->domain = 'local_shipping';
                $this->method_title = __('Pickup', $this->domain);
                $this->method_description = __('Pickup Location for WooCommerce', $this->domain);
                $this->title = __('Pickup Location', $this->domain);
                $this->supports = array(
                    'shipping-zones',
                    'instance-settings',
                    'instance-settings-modal',
                );
            
                $this->instance_form_fields = array(
                    'enabled' => array(
                    'title'         => __( 'Enable/Disable' ),
                    'type'          => 'checkbox',
                    'label'         => __( 'Enable this shipping method' ),
                    'default'       => 'yes',
                ),
                    'title' => array(
                    'title'         => __( 'Method Title' ),
                    'type'          => 'text',
                    'description'   => __( 'This controls the title which the user sees during checkout.' ),
                    'default'       => __( 'Pickup Location' ),
                    'desc_tip'      => true
                ),
                    'tax_status' => array(
                    'title'   => __( 'Tax status', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'type'    => 'select',
                    'class'   => 'wc-enhanced-select',
                    'default' => 'taxable',
                    'options' => array(
                        'taxable' => __( 'Taxable', 'woocommerce' ),
                        'none'    => _x( 'None', 'Tax status', 'woocommerce' ),
                    ),
                ),
                    'cost'       => array(
                    'title'       => __( 'Cost', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'type'        => 'text',
                    'placeholder' => '0',
                    'description' => __( 'Optional cost for pickup.', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'default'     => '',
                    'desc_tip'    => true,
                ),
            );

                $this->enabled = $this->get_option( 'enabled' );
                $this->title   = __('Pickup Location', $this->domain);

                add_action('woocommerce_update_options_shipping_' . $this->id, array($this, 'process_admin_options'));
            }

    public function calculate_shipping( $package = array() ) {
        $this->add_rate( array(
            'id'    => $this->id . $this->instance_id,
            'label' => $this->title,
            'cost'  => 0,
    ) );
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you have tried it is wrong. And it's not recommended to keep the text domain in a variable or a method.

To Create a Custom Shipping Method You have to follow these steps I have corrected on your code.

Hope this helps. You can learn more about how to create new shipping method [here](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-shipping-free-shipping-class-wc-shipping-free-shipping.html). Feel free

```
// To initialize your new shipping method you have to keep it in function 
function local_shipping_init() {
    if ( ! class_exists( Local_Shipping_Method ) ) {
        class Local_Shipping_Method extends WC_Shipping_Method {

            public function __construct( $instance_id = 0 ) {
                $this->id                 = 'local_shipping';
                $this->instance_id        = absint( $instance_id );
                $this->method_title       = __( 'Pickup', 'text-domain' );
                $this->method_description = __( 'Pickup Location for WooCommerce', 'text-domain' );
                $this->title              = __( 'Pickup Location', 'text-domain' );
                $this->supports           = array(
                    'shipping-zones',
                    'instance-settings',
                    'instance-settings-modal',
                );

                // then you have to call this method to initiate your settings
                $this->init();
            }


            public function init() {
                // this method used to initiate your fields on settings 
                $this->init_form_fields();
                // this is settings instance where you can declar your settings field 
                $this->init_instance_settings();
                
                // user defined values goes here, not in construct 
                $this->enabled = $this->get_option( 'enabled' );
                $this->title   = __( 'Pickup Location', 'text-domain' );
                
                // call this action in init() method to save your settings at the backend
                add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_shipping_' . $this->id, array( $this, 'process_admin_options' ) );
            }

            public function init_instance_settings() {
                // you have to keep all the instance settings field inside the init_instance_settings method 
                $this->instance_form_fields = array(
                    'enabled'    => array(
                        'title'   => __( 'Enable/Disable' ),
                        'type'    => 'checkbox',
                        'label'   => __( 'Enable this shipping method' ),
                        'default' => 'yes',
                    ),
                    'title'      => array(
                        'title'       => __( 'Method Title' ),
                        'type'        => 'text',
                        'description' => __( 'This controls the title which the user sees during checkout.' ),
                        'default'     => __( 'Pickup Location' ),
                        'desc_tip'    => true
                    ),
                    'tax_status' => array(
                        'title'   => __( 'Tax status', 'woocommerce' ),
                        'type'    => 'select',
                        'class'   => 'wc-enhanced-select',
                        'default' => 'taxable',
                        'options' => array(
                            'taxable' => __( 'Taxable', 'woocommerce' ),
                            'none'    => _x( 'None', 'Tax status', 'woocommerce' ),
                        ),
                    ),
                    'cost'       => array(
                        'title'       => __( 'Cost', 'woocommerce' ),
                        'type'        => 'text',
                        'placeholder' => '0',
                        'description' => __( 'Optional cost for pickup.', 'woocommerce' ),
                        'default'     => '',
                        'desc_tip'    => true,
                    ),
                );
            }

            public function calculate_shipping( $package = array() ) {
                $this->add_rate( array(
                    'id'    => $this->id, // you should define only your shipping method id here
                    'label' => $this->title,
                    'cost'  => 0,
                ) );
            }
        }
    }

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_shipping_init', 'local_shipping_init' ); // use this hook to initialize your new custom method 

function add_local_shipping( $methods ) {
    $methods['local_shipping'] = 'Local_Shipping_Method';

    return $methods;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_methods', 'add_local_shipping' );
```

The code is tested and works fine. See the screenshot below.

[image]